# Get CPU usage and run a command if it is higher than 80%

Tags: shell-script, cpu-usage

My VPS was hacked several times, hackers put a CPU miner. My hosting provider shutdowns VPS if miner is detected and I did not reactin the next 12 hours. But they can send me notice at 21.00 PM on Saturday :) , and shutdown server at 9.00 AM on Sunday.

So I want to monitor CPU usage and block folder where miner is always revelead from writing.

I'm not very familiar with Linux, so please suggest with such script

1. Check CPU usage, if it is higher than 80% (as example) Do something.
2. In my case - delete all from install folder and make it read only.

Actually I've no idea how to implement item №1.

Comment: You may wish to take a look at `uptime`

Comment: And how would that help?

Comment: The load average roughly tells you to what extent the CPU is occupied, although they are not the same.

Comment: Another solution. If you want to monitor the system and run a specific command when a certain condition about system load is satisfied, you can try installing `monit`. This command is able to handle CPU usage and disk IO and many others.

Comment: If you go for uptime, take the number of processors into account.  From the man's page: `Load averages are not normalized for the number of CPUs in a system, so a load  average  of 1 means a single CPU system is loaded all the time while on a 4 CPU system it means it was idle 75% of the time.`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and had this short `bash` script already done.
It is calculating the load average for the last 15 minutes, if you want a different timeframe, it shold be change (to check the load avg for last 5 min, change the `awk` to `print $1`).
This will tell you the relative usage of the CPUs :

```
#!/bin/bash
cores=$(nproc) 
load=$(awk '{print $3}'< /proc/loadavg)
echo | awk -v c="${cores}" -v l="${load}" '{print "relative load is " l*100/c "%"}'
```

Should run on Ubuntu and Centos.

To get to the point where you check if load is above 80% and 'do something' you should add to this script :

```
usage=$(echo | awk -v c="${cores}" -v l="${load}" '{print l*100/c}' | awk -F. '{print $1}')
if [[ ${usage} -ge 80 ]]; then
    echo "delete all from install folder and make it read only"
fi
```

Comment: good idea, done

Answer (score 0):

> Check CPU usage, if it is higher than 80% (as example) Do something.

Modern CPUs have multiple cores and often each core supports multiple threads. Moreover, cores have often variable clock speed. It is then not that simple to define how to compute a CPU load. Not to mention a single vCPU can only be either 100% idle or 100% busy at any given time. There is no such thing as instantaneous 80% busy CPU.

What you can do is get the average load for each vCPU during a period of time (mpstat provides that) or the average for all vCPUs combined (vmstat).

Even fully CPU bound, if the hostile CPU consumer is single-threaded, it might not blatantly show up in the latter case because other vCPUs might be idle.

If multi threaded and CPU bound, it will be detected by both commands, but you have to make sure it is not a legit application or daemon which is loading your machine.

Another more useful metric is derived from the CPU contention, i.e. measuring how many threads are using and competing for the vCPU resources. This is what the load average is designed to show. Unfortunately, on Linux, the load average is considering a thread uninterruptible state to be CPU load while in fact, the CPU is idle and free to do other tasks so you should pay attention to that factor and identify potential cases where the load average is high but the actual contention is low.

Finally, there might have situations where the run queue is very high but for a very limited period of time. If the load average calculation which use sampling to get the run queue value happen to pick the number at this very peak moment, the load average value will be strongly biased for several minutes or dozens of minutes.

Comment: Mining process takes all avaible CPU to 100%.

Comment: Okay, that simplify the detection. However, given the fact your machine was hacked several times, odds are high hackers still have access to it. The next step would be to reinstall it from scratch with up to date applications/libraries/whatever you run on it, change all passwords and limit the reachable services to what you really need.